# using indexers in c# to get values from struct

Tags: c#, struct, indexer

I have defined a struct as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public struct PacketPenetration
{    
    private Dictionary<double, double[,]> penetration;
    public PacketPenetration(Dictionary<double, double[,]> penetration)
    {        
        this.penetration = penetration;
    }

    public Dictionary<double, double[,]> Penetration { get { return penetration; } }

    public double this[double index1, int index2, int index3]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.penetration[index1][index2,index3];
        }
    }
}
```

and instantiated like this:

```
var penetration = new PacketPenetration();
```

my goal is to be able to add items to `penetration` and be able to get values from it using the indexer defined in the struct. However The following line of code does not work:

```
penetration.Add(3.5, testArray);
```

testArray is a `double[,]`
Where is the problem?

Comment: "does not work" isn't very descriptive. What *happens*? What did you *expect* to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because your `PacketPenetration` doesn't have the method `Add`.

Your indexer is configured for get-only and moreover having indexer does not make the class implement miraculously the method `Add`.

How about adding an `Add` method to `PacketPenetration`:

```
    public void Add(double index , double[,] array)
    {
        penetration.Add(index, array);
    }
```

---

If you really need to pass through the indexer you can add the following :

```
    public double[,] this[double index1, double [,] array]
    {
        set
        {
            this.penetration[index1] = value;
        }
    }
```

Then :

```
  penetration[3.5] =  testArray;
```

Comment: I thought, because the return value is a Dictionary, that would have the Add method. However adding the Add method now throws this error : System.NullReferenceException

Comment: It's because you forgot to mention in your sample code that you have a parameterless constructor ! You should initialize penetration to something if you're using the parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have two things to first:

1. `var penetration = new PacketPenetration();` ==> `var penetration = new PacketPenetration(initializedDictionary);`
   Calling parameter-less constructor will not initialize penetration dictionary. Hence `NullReferenceException`
2. `penetration.Add(3.5, testArray);` ==> `penetration.Penetration.Add(3.5, testArray);`
   Or define `Add` method for the struct